# Interfaz gráfica con Gtk+ en c

Tags: c, gtk, layout, interfaz-gráfica

Es la primera vez que uso Gtk+ y hasta ahora he hecho mi primera ventana, quisiera saber como poder cambiarle el fondo de esta. ¿Alguna recomendación para aprender Gtk?

```c
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    #define WIDTH 1270
    #define HEIGHT 720


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        //Definimos una variable de tipo GtkWidget
        GtkWidget *window;

        //Iniciamos la libreria Gtk
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

        //Creamos una ventana utilizando la variable del tipo GtkWidge
        //Llamando a la función gtk_window_new
        //El tamaño por defecto es de 200x200
        //Solo toma otro parametro: GTK_WINDOW_POPUP
        window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

        //Coloca el titulo de la ventana
        gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Radio");

        //Dimensionar la ventana
        gtk_window_set_default_size(window, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //Posicion de la ventana
        //Puede tomar estos valores
        //GTK_WIN_POS_NONE
        //GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER
        //GTK_WIN_POS_MOUSE
        //GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS
        gtk_window_set_position(window,GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER );

        //Mostramos la ventana con la función gtk_widget_show
        gtk_widget_show(window);

        //Coloca a la ventana en un ciclo donde intercepta eventos
        gtk_main();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que es sencillo. Primero define el color que quieras:

```
//color rojo
GdkColor color;
color.red = 0xffff;
color.green = 0;
color.blue = 0;
```

Modificamos la ventana (gtk 2):

```
gtk_widget_modify_bg(window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
```

Si tienes la versión 3+ ([documentación](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-background-color)):

```
gtk_widget_override_background_color(window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
```